# Fetch data from Firestore Document using StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my Flutter app, I'm trying to get the data from a Document in Firestore. Here's the data I want to get :

[Firestore document's data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxjTl.png)

I need to fetch that `url` from the Document. So far, when I needed to fetch data from a collection, I used a `Streambuilder`. But here I need to fetch data from a document, so I get this error message :

```
late Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>? personnalData =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Decembre')
          .doc(uid)
          .collection('Docs')
          .doc('test')
          .snapshots();

   StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: personnalData, // Error: The argument type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>?'.
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Text('Something went wrong');
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                return Stack(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs
                      .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                        Map<String, dynamic> data =
                            document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;

                        return PageView.builder(
                                            controller: _controller,
                                            itemCount: 3,
                                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                             
                                              return Container(
                                                child: InteractiveViewer(
                                                  minScale: 0.1,
                                                  maxScale: 4.0,
                                                  child: Image.network(
                                                // FETCH URL FROM DOCUMENT 'TEST'
                                                    width:
                                                        MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                            .size
                                                            .width,
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    loadingBuilder: (context,
                                                        child,
                                                        loadingProgress) {
                                                      if (loadingProgress ==
                                                          null) {
                                                        return child;
                                                      } else {
                                                        return Center(
                                                          child:
                                                              
                                                   CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                        );
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            }),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            child: Text('Open'));
                      })
                      .toList()
                      .cast(),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution !

The problem was that I was trying to fetch data from a `DocumentSnapshot` using a `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>` instead of `StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>`

Here's how I solved it :

```
late Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> personnalData =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Decembre')
          .doc(uid)
          .collection('Docs')
          .doc('test')
          .snapshots();

StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: personnalData,
        builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {  
                        return Text(snapshot.data!['url']);
                    }
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }),
```

This code is working well for me. I hope that will help somebody !

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following example:

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    stream:  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Decembre').doc(uid).collection('Docs').doc('test').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                return Column(
                       children:[
                           Text(doc['url'])
                       );
            });
        } else {
        return Text("No data");
        }
    },
)
```

Comment: I get the same error : ```The argument type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'.```

Comment: Just try to replace your code with my code and let me know the result

Comment: I did :) 
But I still get this error : ```The argument type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'.```

Comment: Give me time . Ill get back to you

Comment: I have made, required changes, try now with the following code, let me know if it works out for you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is just to specify the type of the `QuerySnapshot`:

```
late Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> personnalData =  // like this FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Decembre')
      .doc(uid)
      .collection('Docs')
      .doc('test')
      .snapshots();
```

because the `snapshots()` is a method that returns `Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`, and setting only `Stream<DocumentSnapshot>` will be considered as a different type, which throws the error.

Comment: I get this error : ```The argument type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>?'.```

Comment: sorry I did miss a ?, try now

Comment: No, I still get that error even with the ?. 
As you said, ```snapshot()```is supposed to return a ```Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>```, but the problem seems to be that I'm trying to get a ```Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> ``` no ?

Comment: yes this is true, can you tell me where the error is thrown

Comment: The error is thrown inside the StreamBuilder, next to ```stream: personnalData```
I updated my code so you can see.

Comment: I didn't noticied, the `late` promote is as nullable,  you need either to remove the late since it don't have any effect because the `personnalData` has a value, or you can add `!` in the `stream` property like this: `stream: personnalData!,`

Comment: I checked it, let me know if this fixes your issue !

Comment: I tried both ways, but it doesn't solve the issue. I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try

```
 StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
              stream: personnalData,
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Text('Something went wrong');
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
                return Stack(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs
                      .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                        Map<String, dynamic> data =
                            document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;

                        return PageView.builder(
                                            controller: _controller,
                                            itemCount: 3,
                                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                             
                                              return Container(
                                                child: InteractiveViewer(
                                                  minScale: 0.1,
                                                  maxScale: 4.0,
                                                  child: Image.network(
                                                // FETCH URL FROM DOCUMENT 'TEST'
                                                    width:
                                                        MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                            .size
                                                            .width,
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    loadingBuilder: (context,
                                                        child,
                                                        loadingProgress) {
                                                      if (loadingProgress ==
                                                          null) {
                                                        return child;
                                                      } else {
                                                        return Center(
                                                          child:
                                                              
                                                   CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                                        );
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            }),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            child: Text('Open'));
                      })
                      .toList()
                      .cast(),
                );
              },
            ),
```

in streamBuilder you can add <DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> same as you create stream.